# Передача параметров в метод Java

Tags: java

```
public class MainTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //new MyClass();
        int mas[]=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        test(mas);

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Main  "+mas[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void test(int mas[]){
        testA(mas);

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("test  "+mas[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void testA(int mas[]){
        mas[0]=100;
        mas[1]=100;
        mas[2]=100;

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("testA  "+mas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно я что - то не так понимаю. Но по моей логике переменная переданная в метод и дальнейшие модификации с ней должны остаться в это методе, и исчезнуть вместе с методом. Но в итоге я вижу в main измененный массив mas.

Почему так происходит. Потому что в таком случае пропадает надобность в return....В Java давно, а тут такое. Видать что - то серьезное я забыл....

---

```
testA  100
testA  100
testA  100
testA  4
testA  5

test  100
test  100
test  100
test  4
test  5

Main  100
Main  100
Main  100
Main  4
Main  5
```

Comment: В Java параметры в методы передаются _по значениям_ и не меняются, но вот _содержимое_ меняться может. Таким образом ссылка на сам массив (или даже на объект) измениться не может, а элементы массива (или значения полей объекта) - пожалуйста :)

Comment: Посмотрите главу «Подробное рассмотрение особенностей передачи аргументов» в полном руководстве по Java авторства Герберта Шилдта.

Comment: @post_zeew, У вас в доме кран протекает. Что делать?
Идти в библиотеку, брать книгу и сидеть читать, как стать слесарем или позвонить сантехникам и ждать минут 30. 
Пока всех соседей не затопит. 

Было бы правильнее вам в начале помочь решить проблему, а после уже давать советы по книгам. Но в общем спасибо за книгу.

А то ведь так любой может зайти в SO и писать в комментах. 

`Чувак иди в Google там все есть`

Comment: Я ссылаюсь на **конкретную** главу книги, там даже не глава, а несколько абзацев. Книга в свободном доступе в электронном виде. В данном случае я указал именно на главу книги, так как в интернете на эту тему очень много **принципиально неверной информации**. В книге же все **подробно** расписано. И к слову: проблема большинства начинающих программистов заключается в том, что они не читают книги, в которых описываются фундаментальные вещи и не зная **самых азов** начинают писать что-то относительно сложное.

Comment: @post_zeew, или же они просто забывают что - то.

Comment: @AlexChermenin, если резюмировать ваш комент, то вы как раз и говорите, что объект передается по ссылке :)

Comment: Как можно закрыть тему чтобы никто не мог писать больше? Ответ уже дан и выбран

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AlexChermenin замудрено объяснили. Объекты передаются по ссылке, примитивы по значению. Массивы примитивов - это объекты, поэтому передаются также по ссылке.

Обновлено: под передачей по ссылке я имею ввиду, что объект таки передается по значению. Но в значении содержится ссылка на объект, а не копия объекта.

Примитивы (https://ideone.com/c9agyH):

```
int number = 0;

void update(int num) {
    num++;
    System.out.println(num); // 1
}

update(number);

System.out.println(number); // 0
```

Массив примитивов (https://ideone.com/SrzjUd):

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};

void update(int[] nums) {
    for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = 5-i;
    }
}

update(numbers);

/** 
 * Ага, а тут кстати вызывается toString(), чего нет у примитивов
 */
System.out.println(numbers); // {5,4,3,2,1}
```

Comment: Всё передаётся _по значению_, только для объектов ссылка и есть _значение_ :)

Comment: У массивов тоже есть указатели, так как они выделают место в памяти. Так получается?

А не имеет значение что это метод `static` или `обычный`?

Comment: @AlexChermenin под ссылкой вы имете ввиду hashCode?

Comment: Массив - это объект. Изменяя элемент объекта, вы изменяете его по ссылке. Если же вы сделаете так: `for(int num : nums) {
        num = 5;
    }` то ничего не прокатит, потому что вы получите примитивный элемент массива, который получили уже как значение.

Comment: Не путайте, пожалуйста, людей. В Java **все** параметры передается по значению.

Comment: Да, передаются по значению. Но в значении содержится ссылка на объект, а не копия объекта. Моё объяснение проще, чем @Alex Chermenin, но неправильно с точки зрения документации.

Comment: @lampa а кто говорил про копии объектов?

Comment: @lampa спасибо. Вопрос исчерпан)

Comment: @Alex Chermenin исходя из вопроса по моему тс думал, что создается копия при передаче.

Comment: @lampa, вот именно. Даже не копия. А абстрактный массив который живет в методе.

Comment: @lampa все правильно говорите, объекты передаются по ссылке, value по значению. Массив - это объект.

Answer (score 0):

Примитивные типы передаются по значению. Объекты передаются в метод по ссылке. Поэтому все изменения ссылочного объекта влияют на переданный объект. Если переменная примитивный тип, то передается только значение переменной, то есть копия этого значения. И изменения копии никак не влияет на начальное значение.

Представьте себе ссылку, как "пульт управления переменной". Вы передаете в метод только "пульт управления" при передаче по ссылке. При выходе из метода уничтожается только "пульт управления", то есть ссылка. При передаче примитивного типа, происходит передача значения. То есть копируется значение переменной. А при выходе из метода исчезает эта копия. Исчезает значение переменной - копии.

Comment: А как тогда создать клон объекта, чтобы у него был свой указатель, но значения все передались другому объекту. Короче у объекта есть 10 переменных. Чтобы через равно не передавать их все. Можно как  - то одной строкой передать их все другому новому объекту? И как сделать это

Comment: 1. Переопределение метода clone() и реализация интерфейса Cloneable();
2. Использование конструктора копирования;
3. Использовать для клонирования механизм сериализации Ссылка >>> https://habrahabr.ru/post/246993/