# Передача одного массива в разные методы

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, методы

Изучаю потихоньку виды сортировок на Java. Каждую сортировку реализую в отдельном методе. 
Не знаю почему, но в методы ниже **sortBubble** передается уже отсортированный массив. 
Разъясните, как исправить, чтобы в каждый метод, реализующий сортировку, подавался неотсортированный массив, созданный методом **fillArray**

```
public class OneThree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[20];
        fillArray(a);
        sortBubble(a);
        sortSelection(a);
        sortInsert(a);
    }

    static int[] fillArray (int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        return a;
    }

    static void sortBubble (int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = a.length-1; j > i; j--) {
                if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {
                    int tmp = a[j - 1];
                    a[j - 1] = a[j];
                    a[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nСортировка пузырьком:\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    static void sortSelection(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int min = a[i];
            int min_i = i;

            for (int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[j] < min) {
                    min = a[j];
                    min_i = j;
                }
            }
            if (i != min_i) {
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[min_i];
                a[min_i] = tmp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nСортировка выбором:\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    static void sortInsert(int[] arr) {

        int tmp;
        int j;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
                tmp = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = arr[i];
                j = 1;
                while (j > 0 && tmp < arr[j-1]) {
                    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                    j--;
                }
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nСортировка вставками:\n" + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: передавайте в каждый метод свою копию исходного массива. `sortBubble(a.clone())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java массив передается по ссылке - это значит, что вы передаете не копию массива(как с примитивными типами), а ссылку на массив. Когда вы в методе сортируете массив, у вас сортируется не копия, а изначальный массив. А потом вы передаете в остальные методы уже отсортированный массив.

Как написал [Pavel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176119/pavel), передавайте в каждый метод копию исходного массива: `sortBubble(a.clone())`, `sortSelection(a.clone)`, и т.д.

[Более подробно.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769853/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-java)